# please tell me what I'm doing wrong: you need to implement a contact filter by contact name

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, js

js:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getContactList';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class ContactTable extends LightningElement {

    @track contactListRecord;
  
    searchValue;
 
    searchKeyword(event) {
        this.searchValue = event.target.value;
    }
    handleSearchKeyword() {
        
        if (this.searchValue !== '') {
            getContactList({
                searchKey : this.searchValue
                })
                .then(result => {
                    this.contactListRecord = result;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                   
                    const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error',
                        variant: 'error',
                        message: error.body.message,
                    });
                    this.dispatchEvent(event);
                    this.contactListRecord = null;
                });
        } else {
            const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                variant: 'error',
                message: 'Search text missing...',
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<template>

    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
      
        <div class="slds-m-bottom_small">
            <lightning-input 
               type="text"
               label="SEARCH"
               placeholder="Search by name"
               onchange={searchKeyword}
               ></lightning-input>
         </div>
         
         <lightning-button label="FILTER"
            onclick={handleSearchKeyword}
            variant="brand"></lightning-button>
            

    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered contacts">
        <thead>
        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset parent_component">

       <th class="" scope="col">
       <div class="slds-truncate" title="FIRST NAME">FIRST NAME</div>
       </th>

       <th class="" scope="col">
       <div class="slds-truncate" title="LAST NAME">LAST NAME</div>
       </th>

       <th class="" scope="col">
       <div class="slds-truncate" title="EMAIL">EMAIL</div>
       </th>

       <th class="" scope="col">
       <div class="slds-truncate" title="ACCOUNT">ACCOUNT</div>
       </th>

       <th class="" scope="col">
       <div class="slds-truncate" title="MOBILE PHONE">MOBILE PHONE</div>
       </th>

       <th class="" scope="col">
       <div class="slds-truncate" title="CREATED DATE">CREATED DATE</div>
       </th>
       </tr>
       </thead>


       <tbody>
        <template for:each={data} for:item="con">

       <tr key={contact.Id} class="slds-hint-parent child_component">
       
       <th scope="col"> <div class = "slds-truncate">
          {con.FirstName}
         </div> </th>

       <td scope="col"> <div class = "slds-truncate">
        {con.LastName}
       </div> </td>

       <td scope="col"><div class = "slds-truncate">
            <lightning-formatted-email value={con.Email}></lightning-formatted-email>
        </div></td>

       <td scope="col"><div class = "slds-truncate">
        {con.Account.Name}
        </div></td>

       <td scope="col"><div class = "slds-truncate">
           <lightning-formatted-phone value={con.MobilePhone}></lightning-formatted-phone>
        </div></td>

       <td scope="col"><div class = "slds-truncate">
        <lightning-formatted-date-time
        value={con.CreatedDate}
        year="numeric"
        month="numeric"
        day="numeric"
        hour="2-digit"
        minute="2-digit"
        time-zone-name="short">
</lightning-formatted-date-time>
        </div></td>
       </tr>
    </template>
       </tbody>
       </table> 
       </div> 
    
</template>
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class ContactController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<contact> getContactList(string searchKey) {
        string searchKeyword = '%' + searchKey + '%';
        
       
        list<contact> contactListRecord = new list<contact>();
     
       
        list<contact> contactList = [Select id, FirstName, LastName, Email,
                              Account.Name, Phone, CreatedDate
             From Contact
             WHERE FirstName LIKE : searchKeyword];
             
             for(contact con : contactList){
                 contactListRecord.add(con);

        }
        if(contactListRecord.size() == 0){
            throw new AuraHandledException ('No Record Found...'); 
         }
         return contactListRecord;
         
    }      
}
```

Comment: What part doesn't work? Have you looked in your browser's Developer Tools for errors, or at the server-side debug logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to refactor your code for cleaner approach. If you need simple Contact FirstName filter it will be better to implement [wire service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about) (`@wire` decorator with apex `getContactList` adapterId). The `keyword` is reactive property so if the value changes, new data is provisioned and the component rerenders. Morover why don't You use existing standard lwc [lightning-datable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) component with the whole benefit of his inventory.

*contactTable.js*

```js
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from "lwc";
import getContactList from "@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getContactList";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";

const CONTACT_COLUMNS = [
    {
        label: "FIRST NAME",
        fieldName: "FirstName",
        hideDefaultActions: true,
        type: "text"
    },
    {
        label: "LAST NAME",
        fieldName: "LastName"
    },
    {
        label: "EMAIL",
        fieldName: "Email",
        type: "email"
    },
    {
        label: "ACCOUNT NAME",
        fieldName: "AccountName",
        type: "text"
    },
    {
        label: "MOBILE PHONE",
        fieldName: "Phone",
        type: "phone"
    },
    {
        label: "CREATED DATE",
        fieldName: "CreatedDate",
        type: "date-local",
        typeAttributes: {
            year: "numeric",
            month: "numeric",
            day: "numeric",
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit"
        }
    }
];

export default class ContactTable extends LightningElement {
    columns = CONTACT_COLUMNS;
    keyword = "";

    @track rows;

    @wire(getContactList, { searchKey: "$keyword" })
    wiredSearch(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.rows = result.data.map(this.toContactRows);
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.showErrorToast(result.error.body.message);
            this.rows = undefined;
        }
    }

    handleKeywordChange(event) {
        this.keyword = event.target.value;
    }

    toContactRows(row) {
        let contact = {
            ...row,
            AccountName: row.Account?.Name
        };
        return contact;
    }

    showErrorToast(message) {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Error",
            variant: "error",
            message: message
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

*contactTable.html*

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <div class="slds-m-bottom_small">
            <lightning-input
                type="text"
                label="SEARCH"
                value={keyword}
                placeholder="Search by name"
                onchange={handleKeywordChange}
            ></lightning-input>
        </div>
        <lightning-datatable data={rows} columns={columns} key-field="Id"> </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>
```

*ContactController.class*

```
public with sharing class ContactController {
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getContactList(String searchKey) {
        string searchKeyword = '%' + searchKey + '%';

        List<contact> contacts = [
            SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Account.Name, Phone, CreatedDate
            FROM Contact
            WHERE FirstName LIKE :searchKeyword
        ];
        if (contacts.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('No Record Found...');
        }
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!